# Chromium OS refuses to execute binary (crouton) from Download folder

Tags: command-line, chromebook, chromeos, crouton

When ever I try to load ubuntu like using the command:

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t unity
```

I will get the error:

```
sh: 0: Refusing to exec /home/chronos/user/Downloads/crouton from noexec mount
```

if anyone can help or relate please please help I am stuck here

Answer (score 1):

The disk partition you're trying to execute from has been mounted with the `noexec` option (see `man 8 mount` or https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount ), which forbids execution of binaries. Either `cp` the file to a directory on a partition mounted with `exec` (without `noexec`), or fix the way it's mounted.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec,suid,dev,symfollow /home/chronos/user/Downloads/
```

You are not able to execute the script since that is "nonexec mount" which means no scripts can be executed from there. To solve this, give your downloads directory exec permissions with the above command.

The above line of code unmounts and remounts your downloads directory with exec and dev permissions so that scripts can be executed from your downloads directory.

The sudo at the beginning is for root permissions, then the remount statement gives it exec, suid and dev permissions and also disables nosymfollow(but that part is optional) and then I mention the name of the directory, which is your downloads.

Comment: Nice code. Just FYI: We try to aim for instructive answers here. Would you mind expanding your answer to include an explanation of the CLI instruction and why/how it answers/solves the OP question?

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt Thank you so much! I'm new here, I didn't know that. I have now added a brief explaination about what his problem was, what the command did, and how it did it. Thanks for informing me!

Comment: Your explanation was very clear and well written. Nice one.